# How to build nested view model via LINQ query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

This query below returns 4 rows, all rows corresponding an adres info so there is a "adresType" column which represent its HomeAddress, WorkAdress, etc.
And this is AllAddressViewModel:

```
public class AllAddressViewModel
    {
        public AddressModel homeAddress{ get; set; }
        public AddressModel workAddress { get; set; }
    }

    public class AddressModel
    {
        public adresTypeEnum adresType{ get; set; }
        ...
```

This is what I am trying;

```
var result = (       from Muayene in muayeneRepo
                          join Adres in adresRepo on Muayene.HastaTc equals Adres.HastaTc
                          where Muayene.HastaTc == hastaTc.ToString() && Muayene.IsDeleted != true
                          select new HastaMuayeneKayitViewModel()
                          {
                              homeAddress= new AddressModel {
                                  adresType= Adres.AddressType,
                                  ...
                              },
                              workAddress = new AddressModel 
                              {
                                  adresType= Adres.AdresTipi,
                                  ...
```

I think u already understand what bothers me, I should match all adresType with corresponding view model.. How can i populate the model properly within linq, dont want another step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A join like that for a Muayene /w 4 addresses would result in 4 records for the same parent record, each having one address.

If the address records have a discriminating field (address type) then a first step might be to introduce inheritance to your domain model so that a Muayene contains a collection of Addresses, but that collection would contain 0-1 (or more) of each applicable address type as a distinct entity type that inherits from Address. This way you would potentially have an easier time converting these to a corresponding view model. (See Table per Hierarchy inheritance. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618292)

For building the view model structure you will want to group by the Muayene so that you get a group for each parent and it's collection of child addresses or better, utilize navigation properties to handle this.

It's hard to tell from your code sample but if muayeneRepo and addressRepo are Repositories returning IEnumerable or the like based on database tables this will be a potential issue for performance. Normally you'd have these pulling from DBSets. You should also take advantage of navigation properties in your domain so that a Muayene entity has an ICollection of Addresses.

Using a context-based example:

```
var muayenes = _context.Muayenes.Include(x => x.Addresses)
.Where(x => x.HastAc == hastAc && false == x.IsDeleted)
.ToList(); // Materializes these entities so further operations are Linq2Object
```

If you don't have navigation properties and want to join on the DbSets then you can accomplish the same by joining the entities then doing a GroupBy where the group key is the parent entity and the grouped values are the addresses.

The next step I would normally use is either add a constructor or factory class to handle populating a new instance of a view model from my entity, or wiring up something like AutoMapper to do this. Typically I just wire it up myself since it's generally easier to follow than looking elsewhere at mapping rules trying to figure out why something has changed.

for instance:  (Constructor)

```
var viewModels = muayenes.Select(x => new HastaMuayeneKayitViewModel(x)).ToList();
```

or (Factory)

```
var viewModels = muayens.Select(x => HastaMuayeneKayitViewModelFactory.Create(x)).ToList();
```

Addresses can be constructed using the same principles.

The logic for populating the view model and child view models can be moved off to supporting code and re-used rather that ending up in a large Linq expression.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer and explanation.